# I restored a vhost under Webmin, now php script are executed as www-data

Tags: debian, suexec, webmin

Under Webmin (Debian 8), I restored a vhost (without deleting the existing vhost), then I chose 'No' to the question "reallocate UID and GID", now the php scripts run as www-data, I would like the php script to be ran as the user of the vhost as it was initially.